# Can't cURL to other server from web server, but can from localhost

Tags: php, node.js, web-services, curl, server

I have two servers, one is my webserver, for my website, and the other one is my discord bot hosting server. My setup is when a certain action occurs on the webpage, it'll use cURL to post to the node.js server (the discord bot), which would then return some data.When it was in development and I was creating it on my localhost, it worked perfect (both servers were locally hosted). When I take the servers and run them on their respective services, I am given a connection refused error from cURL, same with file_get_contents().

```
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://51.161.93.27:8109/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);   
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( curl_getinfo($ch) ) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_errno($ch) . '<br/>';
    echo curl_error($ch) . '<br/>';
    curl_close($ch);
```

If I run this exact code from localhost instead of the webserver, it works and gets the data. On the webserver I can not post or get.

On the webserver, if I remove the port from the CURLOPT_URL, it'll connect to the main ip and return stuff. Same if I put [www.google.com](http://www.google.com). This means cURL works, just can't connect to the port itself.

Note, the specific port is being run with the node.js http module along with express.

The webserver is being run from namecheap, and using cpanel. The discord bot hosting service is called pebblehosting.

Feel free to use the address, http://51.161.93.27:8109/ to find some more information, its the bot address. If able to succesfully get data from it, it should display a json string with a message stating {"status":"fail. You already have a ticket open"}.

I also connected to the address from services like ping.com and was able to connect.

I have spent all day trying to find a solution, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: In normal server settings, only necessary ports (21, 22, 25, 80, 443, etc ) will be open for connection, but all other ports will be closed). Hence, please check the firewall and make sure that 8109 is open for connection in both servers.

Comment: @KenLee why do i need to check 8109 for both servers? for the bot server i understand, for the web server do you want me to check the bot server ip and port?

Comment: Firewall can block both outbound and inbound traffic. So please check

Comment: hey @KenLee i cant find a firewall setting in my cpanel, but the port is open on my bot server, i also knew this because i was able to connect and cURL to it from localhost.

Comment: my webserver is currently shared hosting, could that be an issue? im planning on upgrading to a vps.